# 会社での出来事を引きずったままだった私 passivity

Tags: parsing

speaker doesn't want to trouble her only family member, A, with her tough day at work. A however, does notice something wrong.

> 会社での出来事を引きずったままだった私の様子がおかしいと、Aは気付いたようだった。

I find this statement is confusing since it 引きずる isn't used in the passive voice.

in other words: I who was tired out("influenced") by the things that happened at work

vs

what is actually written: I who "prolonged" the incidents at work

This doesn't really make sense since a lot of bs that was out of the speaker's control was thrusted upon her at work.

Thanks for any clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Schlep' or 'drag' are probably more appropriate here than 'prolong' or 'influence'.

A noticed that B(?) had a lot on her mind regarding things at work, she had 'dragged her problems home', rather than 'leaving them at the office'.

Another sentence in the same vein:

> 日本人が日本語の構文を引きずったまま英語を書くと、しばしば冗長で複雑な英文が生まれる。
>   When Japanese write in English and drag along Japanese sentence structure, verbose and complicated sentences are created.